# Samsung Galaxy S3 not showing up in eclipse but in device manager?

Tags: driver, adb, galaxy

I know a lot of people have reported almost the same problem but i haven't found the solution yet.

I have eclipse installed.

1. Installed Kies on my computer to get the ADB driver for the phone.
2. I can see the ADBdriver on windows vista.
3. I put the galaxy in developer mode and USB troubleshooting mode.
4. The phone is detected in windows vista. I can see it in windows explorer.
5. If I run adb devices from the "cmd" it does list my phone.

But in eclipse it does not show up?
I have tried reinstalling the drivers a couple of times with no success.

Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem All the time. i just find a single way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 12):

First off, I'm brand new to App development. I installed Eclipse, the add-on, plug-in, sdk, etc. and am following the book "Android for Developers, an App-Driven Approach" in the Deitel Developer Series.

I had the same issue... I could run the sample app in an AVD, but my phone wasn't showing up in the Android Device Chooser. Eclipse wouldn't see my connected phone, so I tried running "adb devices" from the command line in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\

No devices showed up. I ensured the Galaxy was in Developer Mode with USB driver checked.

I could see the Samsung Galaxy S3 in Windows Explorer, and the Device Manager showed an warning with the driver under "Other Devices". I tried "Update Automatically" but that failed.

I went to this address:
http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/SGH-I747MBABMC

I downloaded KIES. Installation took a while (roughly 10 minutes)... it said it was installing a HotFix. Finally, I was prompted to choose items to install along KIES. I selected all three to be safe (Unified Driver Installer, Video Conversion Codec, and Kies Air Message). This took another minute or two.

When Kies came up, it said "please connect a device". I did so. Kies moved to a 'connecting' screen. After a bit, the Device Manager properly stated "SAMSUNG Android Phone" with "SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface device under it" (I'm assuming the driver was installed by Kies which caused the Device Manager to update). Kies still said "Connecting" but it wasn't proceeding so I closed Kies (the device manager seemed to indicate all was working now, and running "adb devices" worked)

It now showed up in Eclipse.

Looks like I *did* need Kies, and it fixed the issue.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 6):

Worked for my S3 using Android 4.3
1. Download Kies 3 from http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/
2. Run it
3. Go to `Tools` > `Reinstall Device drivers`
4. My phone prompted my to allow USB debugging

=> The device showed up in Eclipse "Android Device Chooser"

Answer (score 3):

I followed these steps to make it work :

1. Installed Kies -> Click on tools and 'install driver'
2. Went to device manager right click on the USB for the mobile device and ins

Answer (score 1):

Followed this thread and got it to work. Initially it did not. Some points not mentioned. 
1. When working it shows in the device manager as "Samsung Android Phone"
2. Initially it showed as unauthorised. Need to go to phone and on the popup message authorise.

Other things I tried.
1. In Regedit I deleted all usb  mounted devices hklm/system/mounted devices
2. In Kies I reinstalled the drivers. tools/
3. After I installed Kies did a Windows Update. Nothing new
4. On the device in settings/general/development options I ticked "Show all ANR"
5. In settings/General/Security I unticked "unknown sources"

I am not sure if any of these had an effect but took 5 minutes and it was working. Go figure....

=========

## Warning about deleting mounted devices. It switched my d: and e: drives around which confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the regedit delete hklm\system\mounteddevices (not the hard drives) worked for me.
After installing KIES I plugged my device in. I went to the device manager and my phone was in Others with an  warning tag. When I looked at properties it said the device drivers was not install. In device manager I clicked on update drivers, using internet.

No changed.

In KIES I clicked on tools update drivers. It told me to remove my phone. I did and proceeded. After the update I inserted the phone again.

No change, the device manager said there were errors with the drivers installed.

I removed the device. dos prompt, regedit, navigate to hklm/system/mounteddevices and deleted all accept the harddrives. accepted warning.

I reinserted my phone and clicked on device manager. My phone was there with no errors, "SAMSUNG Android phone/SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface".

I started eclipse and clicked on devices and my phone was there with a question mark and label "unauthorised". I went to the phone and unlocked and accepted message about trusting this computer and ticked the "always" checkbox.

All was good, did a deploy, up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with my windows 8.1 just like yours.
mine wont work with kies.
but I solved it.

some times my problem is gone worse when windows won't detect my Galaxy s3 at all even in Explorer! first I fixed this problem with install "Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1" from this link: [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744)

but for your main problem i find Wondershare MobileGo application. with this you can see your phone on eclips device choser window and can run your apps on it.

you can find it from [here!](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=183693&t=0&i=1)

if any buddy find a better way so let me know.